# Oldboy, Oh Dae-Su meaning "getting through one day at a time"

Tags: intention

In the 2003 movie [Oldboy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364569/), the main character says (in Korean):

> My Name, 'Oh Dae-Su', means getting through one day at a time. That's
>   what 'Oh Dae-Su' means.

Does this make sense in Korean? Is there a play on words that gets lost in the English translation? Or, is it like saying "my name means [whatever  quality]" since this is the most prominent quality?

Is that a possible Korean name at all?

Answer (score 4):

In the movie, he says his name 오대수 is short for "**오**늘만 **대**충 **수**습하며 살자" literally *let's live barely sorting out the day*. Which is a pun made by taking the first syllable of each word in the sentence.

Of course, there is no way that his name actually means that, since names are based on Chinese characters.